# Exchange 2013 - IMAP with Wildcard Cert - Error when Set-ImapSettings

Tags: exchange, ssl-certificate, exchange-2013, wildcard

Trying to get a wildcard cert working on Exchange 2013 for IMAP purposes.  Unable to add in ECP (receives error about it not having a FQDN since its a wildcard)

So then I try to run:

```
Set-ImapSettings -X509CertificateName sub.domain.com
```

However, I receive an error:

> WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of
>   'SERVERNAME\1' have been modified.

It never enables the IMAP setting for this cert.  I have verified with `Get-RoleGroupMember` that I am logged in as someone with Server Management capabilities.  `Running Get-ExchangeCertificates | fl` shows that IMAP service is never tying to this certificate.

Scoured the internet and my mind and can't find why my `Set-ImapSettings` isn't working correctly.

Any suggestions?  Not getting anything in event viewer that points to anything, I've restarted IMAP services (backend and imap4), tried to force enable IMAP service in powershell (`Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbnail xxx -Services imap`), nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show but normally IMAP should still be using the certificate after completing the commands. Did you verify this? Do you get a certificate error when trying to connect to IMAP with a mailbox in Outlook? If it didn't work, then you should get a certificate error (and if you then click "Show Certificate" you should see the self-signed certificate from your Exchange server.